# How to solve : Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0

Tags: android, build.gradle, mapbox-android

I face this problem when trying to use mapbox in Android studio

Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0

what is the problem?

my build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0'
}
```

my build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
  google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }

    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying a version, which actually [exists](https://bintray.com/mapbox/mapbox/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk%3Amapbox-android-sdk)?

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.7'
```

Comment: This is an outdated version. Please see my response below on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Just came across that there are 2 branches that are both under development as it seems. The branch using the old way to access the maven repo (8.x) and the branch using the new way (> 9.4). Still please see my response below on how to use the latest release.

Answer (score 14):

it's just badly explained. you have to make a private token. public token does not work. when you create a token there is a field with "Read:Download" just mark it and generate your token. This token should work.

Answer (score 9):

Version 9.5.0 (and 9.6.0) also exists (See release notes here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md). It is just that the way to access the Maven repository has changed with Mapbox Maps SDK > v9.4.0.

I would discourage you from using an outdated version like `mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.7`, but go for `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.0`.

The new way to access the mave repo is documented here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/#configure-credentials

You now need to create a secret access token and use it to access the maven repo, where the libraries are located. Your module level build.gradle should contain this:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
      authentication {
          basic(BasicAuthentication)
      }
      credentials {
        // Do not change the username below.
        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
          username = 'mapbox'
          // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
          password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error "Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.0.
"

Comment: can you show your module level build.gradle please?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I am also following this [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/#configure-credentials).

Getting the same error @roro roor mentioned.
Could it be, that the error occurs because of the mismatching Gradle dependencies, mentioned in the noted in step 6?

Comment: Looks like it IS a scopes issue. Create a token with Downloads:Read scope should make it work

Comment: The link to the documentation seems to be outdated unfortunately

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still can't resolve Mapbox sdk.

Comment: Be sure you set MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk, not pk!

Comment: @AxesGrinds I have the same issues, even though I followed all answers here... Funny enough downgrading the version to `implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.6.7'` helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just use this safe version and it will work on your gradle.

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'){
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found Solution by generating private key as pointed out in previous answers, and finding an actual version on maven central, neither 9.7 nor 10 was on the maven central repository at the time of writing, using version 9.2 found here

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk

Edit: Was able to use 9.7.0 mapbox by changing settings.gradle entry

repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

to

repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)

and build.gradle to add mavenCentral() and google() to allprojects repositories

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        
        allprojects {
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
                    authentication {
                        basic(BasicAuthentication)
                    }
                    credentials {
                        // Do not change the username below.
                        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                        username = 'mapbox'
                        // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                        password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshot]

The default token Mapbox provides you is what I think you're using, you need to create a new private token and check this permission `DOWNLOAD:READ` then it should work.

I created a new token and named it `first` in my case, you can call it anything.

Answer (score 1):

The only way  got my project to finally work is by looking for some pointers in the project attached here:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/issues/614#issue-988592394
It uses com.mapbox.maps:android:10.0.0-rc.3 and actually works on my machine.

To make my own project work, I had to change settings.gradle from this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Mapbox Map"
include ':app'
```

to this:

```
rootProject.name = "Mapbox Map"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line :  `maven{ url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }`

```
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    /**
    if you using => maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
     so remove this line because mapbox remove repository from https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox
    * */
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
            username = 'mapbox'
            // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
            password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation of Mapbox GL for android here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/.

**As said by the mapbox_gl plugin developers, this is community driven not an official Mapbox product.**

So, do only the https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#configure-credentials part of the documentation for the flutter android project.

- **Create a secret access token** with the `Downloads:Read` scope.
- **Configure your secret token** in android/gradle.properties as `MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=YOUR_SECRET_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN`
- **Configure permissions** in app/source/main/AndroidManifest.xml as:

  ```
  <!-- Always include this permission -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

  <!-- Include only if your app benefits from precise location access. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  ```
- **Keep in mind** to provide the same secret key in the `accessToken` property of the `MapboxMap` widget in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due the credentials; just replace the password from :

password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
or

password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""

To:

password = "Your Token"

and make sure the Token is between double quotes "".